# Split string by decimal numbers PHP

Tags: php

**I have a string like this one:**

> 1.1 Apoyar en la planeación y realización de procedimientos para el mantenimiento de la instrumentación y equipo automatizados. (JEFE DE
>   MANTENIMIENO ELECTRÓNICO, ELÉCTRICO E INSTRUMENTACIÓN.)
>
> 2.1
>     Supervisar
>   que los equipos electrónicos e instrumentación estén trabajando
>   correctamente (JEFE DE MANTENIMIENO ELECTRÓNICO, ELÉCTRICO E
>   INSTRUMENTACIÓN.)

**How can i split it in php to get an array or tuples like:**

> [0] => 1.1
>
> [1]=> Apoyar en la planeación y realización de procedimientos para el mantenimiento de la instrumentación y equipo automatizados. (JEFE DE MANTENIMIENO ELECTRÓNICO, ELÉCTRICO E INSTRUMENTACIÓN.)
>
> [0]=>2.1
>
> [1]=>Supervisar que los equipos electrónicos e instrumentación estén trabajando correctamente (JEFE DE MANTENIMIENO ELECTRÓNICO, ELÉCTRICO E INSTRUMENTACIÓN.)

**or something like:**

> [0]=>1.1
>
> [1]=>Apoyar en la planeación y realización de procedimientos para el mantenimiento de la instrumentación y equipo    automatizados. (JEFE DE MANTENIMIENO ELECTRÓNICO, ELÉCTRICO E    INSTRUMENTACIÓN.)
>
> [2]=>2.1
>
> [3]=>Supervisar que los equipos    electrónicos e instrumentación estén trabajando correctamente (JEFE    DE MANTENIMIENO ELECTRÓNICO, ELÉCTRICO E INSTRUMENTACIÓN.)

**I've been trying with a regular expression with preg_split something like [[0-9].]+ but i don't know if its possible.
Thanks for the help.**

Comment: preg_split with `PREG_DELIM_CAPTURE` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meet [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$testString = '1.1 That big array of 2.1 data which is separated by 2.3 some text';
$testChunks = preg_split('/\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*/', $testString, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($testChunks);
```

Here's a [codepad sample](http://codepad.org/GKMxdMbT) to play with. )

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) to split a string by nearly any pattern.

```
// not tested
preg_split( '/[0-9]{1-99}\.[0-9]{1-99}/', $input );
```

Answer (score 1):

As wrikken commented, [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the `PREG_DELIM_CAPTURE` should do it:

```
preg_split('/\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*/', $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

I also added the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` because it can happen that you will get empty ones (e.g. the empty string at the beginning) and this flag prevents that.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZZ9CjK)

Comment: No problem, it also helped raina77ow, so everybody benefits ;)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty preg_split:

```
$result = preg_split('/([0-9]+.[0-9]+)/',$text,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$items = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++) {
    if ($i%2===0) {
        $items[$result[$i]] = $result[$i+1];
        $i++;
    }
}

print_R($items);
```